# Typing similar code

Tags: coding-style

I've occasionally found myself in situations where I have to type out redundant code... where only one variable or two will change in each block of code.  Usually I'll copy and paste this block and make the necessary changes on each block of code... but is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Generalize, generalize, generalize. You're about halfway there with this question, it's about as general as some code should be in the end. Only that this problem doesn't lend itself too well to generalization.

Answer (score 2):

Heavy use of cut and paste usually means there's something not quite right in the design of the code.  Think about how you could refactor such as breaking out the cut/paste functionality into commonly called methods.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  There is always a better way to do it than copy-and-paste.  You should always get a little uneasy (kind of like you feel when you're about to give a speech in front of a huge crowd) when you're about to hit "Ctrl-V."

In almost any introductory class you're likely to be using a language that has functions, methods, or sub procedures. (What they're called and what they do depends on the language in question).  Any variable that changes needs to be a parameter to that function/method/subprocedure.

When you do that (and the method/function/sub is accessible) you can replace the HUGE chunks of code with a single call to your new m-f-s.

There are a lot of other ways to do this, but when you're just getting started this is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you have a lot of approaches to this situation. I don't know if you're working with OO or structured programming but you can build methods or functions and give them cohesion and unique responsibilities.  I think it's an easy way of thinking...
In the OO paradigm we use some therms on how to avoid this situation: cohesion and low decoupling (you could search for them over the Internet). If you can apply both of them in your code, it will be easier to read and maintain.

That's all